# How do I programmatically set conversionRule for logback?

Tags: java, logback

I have a logback XML configuration file where I use my custom tag converter to tag my log messages.

```
<configuration scan="true"> 
  <conversionRule conversionWord="tag" 
                  converterClass="com.foo.MyCustomTagConverter" />

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <!-- encoders are  by default assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%tag - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

 ...

</configuration>
```

How can I do this programmatically via Java?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class loggerutils {
        static Logger foo = createLoggerFor("foo", "foo.log");
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            foo.info("test");
        }

        private static Logger createLoggerFor(String string, String file) {
            String conversionWord = "tag";
            String converterClass = "com.foo.MyCustomTagConverter";
            LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
            Map<String, String> ruleRegistry = (Map) lc
                    .getObject(CoreConstants.PATTERN_RULE_REGISTRY);
            if (ruleRegistry == null) {
                ruleRegistry = new HashMap<String, String>();
            }
            lc.putObject(CoreConstants.PATTERN_RULE_REGISTRY, ruleRegistry);
            ruleRegistry.put(conversionWord, converterClass);

            PatternLayoutEncoder ple = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
            ple.setPattern("%-20tag %-30(%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread]) - %-15(%M) - %-5level -%logger{32} - %msg%n ");

            ple.setContext(lc);
            ple.start();

            ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
            consoleAppender.setEncoder(ple);
            consoleAppender.setContext(lc);
            consoleAppender.start();

            Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(string);
            logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
            logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
            logger.setAdditive(false); /* set to true if root should log too */
            logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
            logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
            logger.setAdditive(false);
            return logger;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A wall of code isn't really an answer, some context would be useful.

Comment: Why is the code not useful? The OP asked how to do this programmatically.   The code is the context. Is there a line of code that is confusing?

Comment: I never used to get this, but now I do: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext`

Comment: The converter related code works fine with Logback 1.2.3.